# RabbitMQ crash, messages won't be delivered after restart

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

Here is the situation (all running local on my dev machine):

1. I got a client (consumer) connected and waiting for messages.
2. I use the RabbitMQ admin to publish messages and consumer get them.
3. I manually kill RabbitMQ (I'm using docker locally, I simulate a sudden crash by using `docker kill` the RabbitMQ instance).
4. I use the RabbitMQ admin to publish messages but this time the messages got stuck in the queue.
5. If I reset the client then the messages got delivery.

Did I miss some configuration to check the connection is alive?

Background data:

- Consumer is node app v8.9.4
- RabbitMQ v3.7.7
- Local machine macOS 10.13.6

Comment: Won't resetting the client empty the queues?

Comment: yes, reseting the client will empty the queue... I want to know if there is a way to get the messages without reseting the client.

Comment: One possible solution is to requeue the messages. You can look at [this](https://blog.forma-pro.com/rabbitmq-retries-on-node-js-1f82c6afc1a1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905721/rabbitmq-unacked-message-not-going-away-after-broker-restart) for implementation according to you.